# Summing an Attribute Based on other Attributes in a list

Tags: python, list, count, counter, frequency

Basically I have a csv file with data as shown:

```
['Store A', '2015-03-04', '00948', 'Red','A','AA']
['Store C', '2015-05-06', '00948', 'Blue','A','BB']
['Store B', '2015-07-08', '101130', 'Red','B','CC']
['Store A', '2015-09-10', '111011', 'Blue','C','DD']
['Store C', '2015-10-11', '101510', 'Red','A','EE']
['Store B', '2015-11-12', '101459', 'Red','B','FF']
['Store C', '2015-15-04', '01836', 'Blue','C','GG']
['Store B', '2015-30-05', '02201', 'Blue','A','HH']
['Store A', '2015-18-06', '04022', 'Red','C','II']
['Store C', '2015-07-07', '11056', 'Blue','B','JJ']
['Store C', '2015-08-05', '10149', 'Red','D','KK']
['Store A', '2015-10-04', '113569', 'Red','A','LL']
['Store B', '2015-12-03', '005410', 'Blue','C','MM']
['Store A', '2015-15-02', '053410', 'Blue','E','NN']
['Store A', '2015-16-04', '113410', 'Red','J','OO']
```

I wanted to determine how many times the word 'Blue' occurred for each of the list, such that the output is basically the sum of the word 'Blue' given the first attribute which is Store A, B and C, the needed output should be :

```
['Store A','Blue','2']
['Store B','Blue','2']
['Store c','Blue','3']
```

my code is as follow:

```
csvReader = csv.reader(open('count.csv','rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for line in csvReader:
    print line.count('Blue')
```

apparently the result is:

```
>>> 
0
0
0
.
.
.
.
0
0
```

I also tried the code:

```
csvReader = csv.reader(open('count.csv','rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for line in csvReader:
    count_blue= [[x, line.count('Blue')] for x in set(line)]
    print count_blue
```

it also does not give me the needed output. What seems to be my mistake? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your delimiter is set to `,`. It will split your input based on `,` and not newlines. Try `print(line)` inside your `for` loop so you can see exactly what lines are being fed.

Comment: Does your csv really contain that data (python lists)? or you put python representation of data here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your CSV file is in fact a CSV file. Comma is the delimiter and the quotechar is the single quote char `'`.

Counting the number of times that (zero-based) column 3 occurs for each store in column 0 requires grouping the data by column 0. One way to do that is with a dictionary. A `collections.defaultdict` is a type of dictionary that makes it easy to collect lists of values with a common key. Once you have that you can produce counts of the "Blue" items, or "Red", or whatever else you might have.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list) 
with open('count.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f, quotechar="'"):
        d[row[0]].append(row[3])

    for k in sorted(d):
        print('{},{}'.format(k, d[k].count('Blue')))
```

**Output**

```
Store A,2
Store B,2
Store C,3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! it helps!

Comment: Hi @TouyaD.Serdan if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look like a CSV file, it looks like one Python list per line. Read it with `literal_eval` and feed it to a `Counter`:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from collections import Counter

blues = Counter()
with open("count.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        ls = literal_eval(line)
        if ls[3] == 'Blue':
            blues[ls[0]] += 1
```

If you want to print it in your desired output format:

```
for key in blues:
    print("['{}', 'Blue', {}]".format(key, blues[key]))
```